# Did I do something wrong in solving the functional equation $2f(x+y)+6y^3=f(x+2y)+x^3$ or does it have no solutions?

Tags: functions, solution-verification, functional-equations

I was trying to solve this functional equation that I found in some papers.
$$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$2f(x+y)+6y^3=f(x+2y)+x^3$$ for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

First, I made $x=y=0$. Then:
$$2f(0)+0=f(0)+0$$
$$f(0)=0$$

I then made $x=-y$. I get:
$$2f(-y+y)+6y^3=f(-y+2y)+(-y)^3$$
$$2f(0)+7y^3=f(y)$$
Because we know that $f(0)=0$, we can say that:
$$f(x)=7x^3$$

But when I try to use $f(x)=7x^3$ in the original functional equation I don't get something that is equal for every $x,y$. Does that mean there are no solutions to this functional equation or did I do something wrong?

Comment: It's inconsistent. If you put $y=0$ you get $f(x)=x^3$.

Comment: @Chrystomath does this mean that there is no complete solution?

Comment: You did nothing wrong. A solution does not exist otherwise it would be $f(x)=7x^3$ unless of course you made an error plugging that $f$ in the original equation.

Comment: @JCAA thank you! I tried it three times, so I'm pretty certain I did not make a mistake.

Comment: Then this equation has no solutions. This happens quite often.

Comment: You can think of a functional equation as a infinite system of equations on values of the function. Sometimes we get extraneous solutions like in this case. Or think of it like this $x+2y=3,2x-y=1$ has a unique solution but $x+2y=3,2x-y=1,x+3y=2$ does not.

Comment: For $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$2\,f(x+y)-f(x+2y)=ax^3+by^3\text{ for all }x,y\in\mathbb{R}$$ if and only if $a=b=0$ (in which case, the only solution is given by $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 5):

Can we make this a sensible problem?  Maybe a functional equation not over the reals, but over some other field?  We already have $7x^3 = x^3$, so $6=0$, so the characteristic is either $2$ or $3$.

Yes.  In fact, $f(x) = x^3$ does satisfy this functional equation over any field of characteristic $2$ or $3$.